# Cannot resolve module 'jqwidgets-framework' npm

Tags: npm, webpack, jqwidget

I have installed the module `jqwidgets-framework` from npm.
It should be the official as it's stated on jqwidgets.com

When I try to import it with :

```
import jqx from 'jqwidgets-framework';
```

I get the error when I bundle it with webpack.

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jqwidgets-framework'

I know that the syntax works as I import knockout and jquery the same way.
If anyone has got it to work I would like to know.

Comment: have you solved your issue? I too have a similar problem.

Comment: Yes, i did solve it. The jqwidgets-framework node module was missing a main method in the package.json file. So it didnt point to a file when it was required/ imported. I have mentioned it to them on the jqwidgets forum.

Answer (score -1):

The proper way to install the **jqwidgets-framework** npm package is:

```
npm i jqwidgets-framework
```

or:

```
npm install jqwidgets-framework
```

Sources:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jqwidgets-framework
- http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/package-managers/npm-tutorial.htm

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i have already installed it via  npm install jqwidgets-framework

Comment: Just quoting the docs isn't an answer, especially when neither the quoted docs, nor the proposed solution solve anything. If you're going to answer a question on StackOverflow, you should at least test a little bit that your answer would solve the OP's problem.